# byobu not autoresizing and filling the window

Tags: gnu-screen, byobu

I started a putty window, changed the font, and then did Windows-Left to fit it to the left side of the screen and it decided to do the screenshot below. The only way i've found to make it go away is the log off/on but that's obviously impractical and doesn't fix the problem.

I've had it in the past but not this bad. It usually happens when I move or resize the window. Is there a setting to have it just auto resize by default?

[edit] and then, about :05 later out of nowhere, it popped away. I'm just sitting here doing something else and it changed back to normal.

[image: this?]

Answer (score 17):

That means that you (or someone else) is connected to the same Byobu session from another computer with a smaller terminal size.

You should be able to kick the other session using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: That wasn't the case. This is a local dev VM. The vm console was sitting at login prompt and I had no other sessions open. This has been the case each time this kind of thing happens. `w` shows only me. It was prompted by a putty window change. Next time it occurs i'll use `alt-f6` anyway and see what happens.

Comment: unfortunately, `alt-f6` doesn't work from mac. And it does a detached session :(

Answer (score 1):

For mac user, by querying from the help info `ctrl-a + ?`, one could simply run the bash script `$BYOBU_PREFIX/lib/byobu/include/tmux-detach-all-but-current-client` to kick other sessions.